# Replacing vim colors without inventing color scheme

Tags: vim

I don't want to learn how to create a new scheme. I just want to **replace some color with another color  everywhere** in default color scheme.

This is how default.vim (default color scheme by Bram Moolenaar) looks like with comments removed:

```
hi clear Normal
set bg&

hi clear

if exists("syntax_on")
  syntax reset
endif

let colors_name = "default"
```

As you see it doesn't define any colrs it uses whatever the colors used to be (in C code, I guess).

So, how can I **replace  some color with another color**  everywhere?

Example: default color scheme highlights some groups of text with color 'ugly' and I want it to highlight it with colour 'neutral'.

Is question clear enough now?

Answer (score 1):

```
                    *:hi-default* *:highlight-default*
The [default] argument is used for setting the default highlighting for a
group.  If highlighting has already been specified for the group the command
will be ignored.  Also when there is an existing link.

Using [default] is especially useful to overrule the highlighting of a
specific syntax file.  For example, the C syntax file contains: >
    :highlight default link cComment Comment
If you like Question highlighting for C comments, put this in your vimrc file: >
    :highlight link cComment Question
Without the "default" in the C syntax file, the highlighting would be
overruled when the syntax file is loaded.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to replace a color everywhere in Vim.  First, use the `:highlight` command in vim to view a sample of all the predefined color groups.  You should also read the output of `:help highlight` to see the definitions of all the color highlighting groups.

Once you have identified the group you want to change the a candidate replacement group (with a better color), use a command like this:

```
" Fix the difficult-to-read default setting for search/replace text
" highlighting.  The bang (!) is required since we are overwriting the
" DiffText setting.  Use the ":highlight" command in vim to see
" alternate color choices if you don't like "Todo" or "StatusLine"
highlight! link   IncSearch  Todo           " Yellow 
highlight! link      Search  StatusLine     " Light tan 

" Fix the difficult-to-read default setting for diff text highlighting.
" The bang (!) is required since we are overwriting the DiffText
" setting. The highlighting for "Todo" also looks nice (yellow) if you
" don't like the "MatchParen" (Aqua) diff color.
highlight! link DiffText MatchParen     " Aqua 
"   highlight! link DiffText Todo       " Yellow
```

The vim help for `highlight` shows you can also specify colors as hex RGB like:

```
:highlight Comment guifg=#11f0c3 guibg=#ff00ff
```

There is also a lot of good information to be found by using `:help syntax`.

As always, once you have found the colors you like, you should save them in your ~/.vimrc file (saved in Git, of course!) so they are applied automatically every time you fire up GVim.